# How can I disable Sketch App from checking for updates?

Tags: sketch-app

I only use sketch maybe once every few months and the most basic features. When I need to use it, I need to use it in a hurry and don't want the confronting and intrusive updates available box to pop up. It's very unlikely that I'd be using any new features, and it's very unlikely that there are bugs with the basic features that I do use – and if I did have problems with them, I would manually update anyway.

(Besides the bad user experience, – I was using internet on a flight not long ago, I didn't download the update for Sketch of course, but just the process of checking for the update itself cost me money, even though it was only exchanging a few kilobytes.)

Is there a way to disable checking for updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run

```
defaults write com.bohemiancoding.sketch3.plist SUEnableAutomaticChecks -bool false
```

on the command line (ie in Terminal). I got this from the Sketch support team.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful to me. Just a follow-up question: how to undo this change, in case I ever want for Sketch to automatically check for updates again? Can I still check for updates manually after running this command? Will uninstalling Sketch and installing it again undo whatever this command does? Thanks!

Comment: @FabioBracht I'm not sure, but I'd suspect running the same command again with `true` instead of `false` at the end.